# Google map is not loading in angular routing

Tags: google-maps, angular, angular-routing

I am using angular routing in index.php and in one of contact.php.I am using google map so when I navigate to contact.php, google map is not showing but when hit ctrl + f5 refresh the page map is showing, I don't know where I am doing wrong because there is no error showing in the console log. Please help me.

here is my code for routing and redirect.Both are not working. Thanks in Advance.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "home.php"
})
.when("/about", {
    templateUrl : "about.php"
})
.when("/contact", {
    templateUrl : "contact.php"
})
.when("/mission", {
    templateUrl : "mission.php"
})
.when("/leadership", {
    templateUrl : "leadership.php"
})
.when("/product", {
    templateUrl : "product.php"
}).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

here is my contact.php page code

```
<div class="margin-bottom-90 fix">              
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div id="contact-map"></div>
            </div>          

            <div class="contact-form col-sm-6 ">
                <h2>contact form</h2>
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="input-box transparent"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*"></div>
                    <div class="input-box transparent"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*"></div>
                    <div class="input-box transparent"><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"></div>
                    <div class="input-box transparent"><textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea></div>
                    <div class="input-box submit-box width-full"><input type="submit" value="send" class="button large"></div>
                </form>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular, google maps. map not loading with template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452755/angular-google-maps-map-not-loading-with-template)

Comment: i solve by my self by using google map in angular controller